# How long does the fireDate of a UILocalNotification survive its processing?

Tags: ios, notifications

As part of `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol, an app is waiting to be called when some (local) user notification was activated by the user, i.e. touched in the pull down, lock screen, etc.. After such notification had been scheduled by the app with a `.fireDate` in the (then) future, I have not always seen values of `.fireDate` later on: When the notification object got passed to the application by the system, then its `.fireDate` was either present and could be manipulated, or it was `nil`. (In all cases tested, the notification objects *did* have a `.fireDate` set, and in the future, before they had been posted, or scheduled, by the app.)

Thus, will `.fireDate` survive in the notification center? That is, will the `assert` in the following example evaluate a true expression always? Even when a notification had been lingering in the user's notification center for a day or so? Or is `.fireDate` subject to state change of the notification or its center? (Or am I barking up the wrong tree?)

```
func application(
    application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {

        if let _ = notification.region {
            // not interested
        } else {
            assert(notification.fireDate != nil)
        }
}
```

(The date in question will eventually be stored somewhere else, being a model thing, but `.fireDate` seemed to be so convenient and to the point!)